# How to Enable JavaScript for wget in linux for grabbing a website?

Tags: linux, wget, javascript, scraping

I use wget like this for save site :
`wget --page-requisites --no-parent --mirror http://example.com/index.html -P /home/`
in Some cases It **does NOT** work, Error is :

```
This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support
```

Now How can I enable Javascript support for that or another way for thease sites.

Comment: You don't, because you can't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901661/wget-javascript ?

Comment: This Topic Solved My Problem, Thanks Tolsadus<br/> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901661](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901661)